# How to trigger HTTP request with a button?

Tags: node.js, http, iot

Literally, with a physical button. Say I had a Node.js/Express server and I wanted to trigger HTTP requests by pressing a physical button; how would I go about doing that?

Comment: can you post you button html code

Comment: is the server running on the same device which has the button connected to it?

Comment: I hesitate to link w3schools, but https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_raspberrypi_led_pushbutton.asp might get the job done for you - in combination with the `request` npm library